# How can I make an NSDictionary from this data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, nsdictionary

I have a tableview with cells with each has a `UITextField` in it.  Right now I'm manually setting this data from a `NSDictionary` to each cell and I'm setting a property of UITextField to each cell's UITextField.  This sets the `textField`'s text to the text from the dictionary if there is any, but if there is not, I want the user to be able to set the text into a new NSDictionary that I can upload back to the server.

But I think I need to create a `NSDictionary` to store the new values.  Right now, the text in the cells is getting erased and randomly reused as the table is scrolled off/in view.

```
else if (tableView == self.vitalsTableView)
    {
        if ([indexPath row] == 2) {
            CellIdentifier = @"bloodPressureCell";
            BloodPressureTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            self.bloodPressureTextField1 = cell.textField1;
            self.bloodPressureTextField2 = cell.textField2;
            return cell;
        }
        else if ([indexPath row] == 9){
            CellIdentifier = @"statusCell";
            SmokingStatusTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            return cell;
        }
        else if ([indexPath row] == 10){
            CellIdentifier = @"vitalsCell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            return cell;
        }
        else{
            CellIdentifier = @"textCell";
            VitalsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Temperature";
                    cell.textField.text = [self.childAppointmentDictionary objectForKey:@"temperature"];
                    self.temperatureTextField = cell.textField;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Pulse";
                    cell.textField.text = [self.childAppointmentDictionary objectForKey:@"pulse"];
                    self.pulseTextField = cell.textField;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cell.textField.text = [self.childAppointmentDictionary objectForKey:@"respiratory_rate"];
                    self.respiratoryRateTextField = cell.textField;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Oxygen Saturation";
                    cell.textField.text = [self.childAppointmentDictionary objectForKey:@"oxygen_saturation"];
                    self.oxygenSaturationTextField = cell.textField;;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Height";
                    cell.textField.text = [self.childAppointmentDictionary objectForKey:@"height"];
                    self.heightTextField = cell.textField;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Weight";
                    cell.textField.text = [self.childAppointmentDictionary objectForKey:@"weight"];
                    self.weightTextField = cell.textField;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"BMI";
                    cell.textField.text = [self.childAppointmentDictionary objectForKey:@"bmi"];
                    self.bmiTextField = cell.textField;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Pain (1-10)";
                    cell.textField.text = [self.childAppointmentDictionary objectForKey:@"pain"];
                    self.painTextField = cell.textField;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return cell;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there a very specific requirement for using only the tableView ? We have other options to show as well as add data.

Answer (score 0):

Cells are destroyed when off screen, so any data in them that doesn't exist somewhere else will be destroyed as well.

Cells are views - not models - so be sure to keep you data in a model that the controller asks for to give to the view.

Comment: Right, so how can I get a modal hooked up in my situation given the way I'm setting the text right now?

Comment: Store it however you want - NSDictionary, NSArray, etc. Just keep sure to keep that collection alive, probably by adding it as a property of your controller. It's hard for me to get more specific without really knowing your code and the expected life cycle of the data.

Comment: Well isn't the initial `textField`'s text being stored/retrieved from `childAppointmentDictionary` based on my code?

Comment: Change this: self.temperatureTextField = cell.textField; to self.temperatureTextField.text = cell.textField.text; I think you are setting the pointers to be the same, so when the textField is destroyed your pointer it too.

Comment: Again, it is hard to debug this stuff without knowing the context.

Comment: I think I just need to write the textfeild's text back to the childAppointmentDictioary, instead of setting it to an NSString?